# Sidebar Form -- No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes

I have a contact form that works fine when I load the form page by itself using the URL. Now I have redesigned the site and the form is now being rendered in a sidebar and I get a posting error when I hit the submit button from within the sidebar.

Now if I load the form page using the URL the sidebar works as long as I stay on the form page, as soon as I change pages the sidebar form will throw the ‘No routes matches `[Post]` ‘ error again when I hit the submit button.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Scott

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root 'static_pages#index'


  get 'home'    => 'static_pages#index'

  get   'video'   => 'static_pages#video'

  get   'help'    => 'static_pages#help'

  get   'about'   => 'static_pages#about'

  get   'services'   => 'static_pages#services'

  get     'accordion' => 'static_pages#accordion'

  get   'social' => 'static_pages#social'

  get   '/messages' => 'messages#new'
  post  '/messages' => 'messages#create'



end

Messages_Controller

class MessagesController < ApplicationController

   def new
    @message = Message.new
   end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)

    if @message.valid?
      MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Your Messages Has Been Sent."
      redirect_to messages_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Please Fill in All of the Fields."
      render :new
    end

end

private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :content)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much figured this out.

I wrapped my form in a form_tag helper like this:

```
<%= form_tag("messages", method: "post", :class => "my-styles") do %>
...my form here...
<% end %>
```

and that solved the "**No Routes Match POST** issue.

Then to stay on the same page after submitting the form information I modified the MessagesController to redirect_to(:back) like this:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController


def new
@message = Message.new
end


def create
@message = Message.new(message_params)

if @message.valid?
  MessageMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
  flash[:notice] = "Your Messages Has Been Sent."
  redirect_to(:back)

else
  flash[:alert] = "Please Fill in All of the Fields."
  redirect_to(:back)

end

end


private

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :content)
end

end
```

Thanks to the Stack **Overflow** community as I gathered just about all of what it took to figure this out from these very pages.

Thanks All,

Scott